# Puppeteer in Docker not loading web fonts

Tags: linux, docker, google-chrome, fonts, puppeteer

When running Puppeteer inside Docker, some external font-face fonts are not loaded.

As an example, when accessing `https://misli.com` and intercepting resources requests through `page.on('request')` shows that the font files are never requested. However, when running puppeteer directly in local OSX (outside Docker), the fonts are correctly downloaded.

See example Puppeteer script:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      args: ['--ignore-certificate-errors','--no-sandbox','--disable-setuid-sandbox']
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.setRequestInterception(true)
    page.on('request', async (request) => {
        if(request.resourceType() == 'font'){
            console.log(request.url())
        }   
        await request.continue()
    })
    
    await page.goto('https://misli.com/',  {waitUntil : "networkidle2"})
    await page.evaluateHandle('document.fonts.ready')
    await browser.close()
})()
```

And the output outside Docker (inside Docker the output is blank):

```
https://st.misli.com/build/fonts/barlow-v5-latin-ext_latin-regular.af51b9c.woff2
https://st.misli.com/build/fonts/barlow-v5-latin-ext_latin-600.fe20152.woff2
https://st.misli.com/build/fonts/barlow-v5-latin-ext_latin-500.d9d4d40.woff2
https://st.misli.com/build/fonts/barlow-v5-latin-ext_latin-700.6a5f5c7.woff2
https://st.misli.com/build/fonts/barlow-v5-latin-ext_latin-800.6a6ccfb.woff2
```

See here the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ARG REQUIREMENTS_FILE
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential \
                        screen \
                        less \
                        vim \
                        xmlsec1 \
                        libx11-xcb1 \
                        gconf-service\
                        libasound2\
                        libatk1.0-0\
                        libc6\
                        libcairo2\
                        libcups2\
                        libdbus-1-3\
                        libexpat1\
                        libfontconfig1\
                        libgcc1\
                        libgconf-2-4\
                        libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0\
                        libglib2.0-0\
                        libgtk-3-0\
                        libnspr4\
                        libpango-1.0-0\
                        libpangocairo-1.0-0\
                        libstdc++6\
                        libx11-6\
                        libx11-xcb1\
                        libxcb1\
                        libxcomposite1\
                        libxcursor1\
                        libxdamage1\
                        libxext6\
                        libxfixes3\
                        libxi6\
                        libxrandr2\
                        libxrender1\
                        libxss1\
                        libxtst6\
                        ca-certificates\
                        fonts-liberation\
                        libappindicator1\
                        libnss3\
                        lsb-release\
                        xdg-utils\
                        wget\
                        libgconf-2-4\
                        libgbm-dev\
                        xfonts-utils

RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
&& sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y google-chrome-unstable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf \
  --no-install-recommends \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*t

ADD https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.0/dumb-init_1.2.0_amd64 /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init

ADD --chown=node:node ./ /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app

USER node
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH=$PATH:/home/node/.npm-global/bin
ENV NODE_PATH=/home/node/app/node_modules

RUN npm install
RUN npm install run-func supervisor forever -g

EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]
# CMD ["node", "server.js"]
CMD ["forever","server.js"]
```

Is there anything missing in the Docker definition?

Comment: Did you ever get fonts working in a docker container properly? Same thing happening here. I included the fonts in my Dockerfile when building. I run `fc-list` inside the container and it shows my font as present & valid. Rendering the document to the browser shows the font correctly, but when running it through puppeteer, it does not use the font. These options did not help me. https://www.browserless.io/blog/2020/09/30/puppeteer-print/